# How to use material fonts and icons locally with material-ui?

Tags: reactjs, webpack, material-ui

I do not have Internet access when running my material-ui application so I want to install locally the Material Design icons and fonts. I have been unable to do so. For example, I tried to use the icons by:

1. Downloading and copying the icon fonts to my styles folder
2. Reference the fonts in the main.css of my application as suggested by [Google](http://google.github.io/material-design-icons/#setup-method-2-self-hosting)
3. Import the main.css in my application (I am using webpack)

   But, the **FontIcon** component does not show the icon.

In my main.css I have:

```
@font-face {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-style: normal;
  font-weight: 400;
  src: url(material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.eot); /* For IE6-8 */
  src: local('Material Icons'),
  local('MaterialIcons-Regular'),
  url(material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2) format('woff2'),
  url(material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff) format('woff'),
  url(material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf) format('truetype');
}

.material-icons {
  font-family: 'Material Icons';
  font-weight: normal;
  font-style: normal;
  font-size: 24px;  /* Preferred icon size */
  display: inline-block;
  line-height: 1;
  text-transform: none;
  letter-spacing: normal;
  word-wrap: normal;
  white-space: nowrap;
  direction: ltr;

  /* Support for all WebKit browsers. */
  -webkit-font-smoothing: antialiased;
  /* Support for Safari and Chrome. */
  text-rendering: optimizeLegibility;

  /* Support for Firefox. */
  -moz-osx-font-smoothing: grayscale;

  /* Support for IE. */
  font-feature-settings: 'liga';
}
```

And in index.js I have:

```
import "./assets/styles/main.css";
```

Answer (score 5):

According to `css-loader`'s [documentation](https://github.com/webpack/css-loader):

> @import and url(...) are interpreted like require() and will be resolved by the css-loader.

So, if you are using css-loader, this should be working "out of the box". Make sure your CSS loader looks a bit like:

```
{ test: /\.css$/, loader: "style-loader!css-loader" }
```

#### So.. if are you already doing this..

Since you are using webpack, you could have a look at the [webpack file-loader](https://github.com/webpack/file-loader). You'll need to include it in your `loaders` array in the `module` object within your webpack config.

To install the fileloader if you do not have it:

`npm install file-loader --save-dev`

And a sample loader:

```
{
    test: /\.(eot|svg|ttf|woff|woff2)$/,
    loader: 'file?name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]'
}
```

You may need to play around with the `name` attribute and the path that you include the fonts in your CSS. The name directory in the above loader is where the file-loader dumps the files (often your `outpath.path` in `webpack.config.js` if one has been defined). Run webpack and see what it gives you.

#### Or..

You could also embed the font file as a base-64 encoded data-uri blob. To do that, install the `url-loader` and use something like the following loaders. This time you need to specify a mime-type, so each file needs it's own loader with it's respective mime-type

```
{ test: /\.svg$/, loader: 'url?limit=65000&mimetype=image/svg+xml&name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]' },
{ test: /\.woff$/, loader: 'url?limit=65536&mimetype=application/font-woff&name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]' },
{ test: /\.woff2$/, loader: 'url?limit=65536&mimetype=application/font-woff2&name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]' },
{ test: /\.[ot]tf$/, loader: 'url?limit=65536&mimetype=application/octet-stream&name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]' },
{ test: /\.eot$/, loader: 'url?limit=65536&mimetype=application/vnd.ms-fontobject&name=material-design-icons/iconfont/[name].[ext]' }
```

Note, however, that I have set a limit of 64K for each file as browser support for data-uri blob's over 64K isn't so great, although you may be okay to remove this.

I personally suggest trying the file-loader method.

#### And if you are still having problems..

You should be able to `require` your files in your CSS. Use this in combination with the file-loader above. require returns the path to the asset, so it's possible to require inside the value of your CSS attribute. Which would end up looking like this:

```
@font-face {
  /* .... */ 
  url(require('material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff2')) format('woff2'),
  url(require('material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.woff')) format('woff'),
  url(require('material-design-icons/iconfont/MaterialIcons-Regular.ttf')) format('truetype');
  /* .... */
}
```